# How can I get my image swap to work in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple "coming soon" page and for the life of me cannot figure out how to create an image link that, when hovered over, changes to another image.
I've trawled google and cannot find an answer that works.
I am guessing I am missing something obvious and have overlooked it. 
I feel like I can't see the wood for the trees.

Html :

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Ablockalypse</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Ablockalypse">
  <meta name="author" content="Coming Soon">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">


</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <img src="images/cityscape.png">
  <div id="header">
    <img src="images/banner.png">
  </div>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="images/Logo.png">
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/info_red.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet :

```
body {
    background-color: #746747
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 6%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;   
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    -ms-transform: rotate(13deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(13deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(8deg);
}

#info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left:290px;
    width: 276px; 
    height: 134px;
    background-image: url(images/info_red.png) no-repeat;;
}

#info :hover {

    background-image: url(images/info_green.png) no-repeat;;
}
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: A demo with image (you can use dummy images from lorempixel.com) would be more use here I think than just bare code.

Comment: You have an `<img>` element and a `background-image`, both seemingly pointed to the same image file. In addition to the answer(s), you may be looking at the `<img>`, which would not change on hover.

Comment: good catch @MikeMcCaughan. i saw the space first, answered hastily, then saw the image and back-ground image. smh (not that the space isn't significant, just not the only issue)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Ok, so do I lose one and keep the other or do I need to change one of them? I did try that already with no joy but maybe I'm missing something again.
(My brain is fried!!)

Comment: I'd lose the `<img>`, and the space after the `#info` in `#info :hover` and it should work. If not, there's something else happening we can't see.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I lost the <img> from html document (I wasn't sure what you meant so deleted just the "img" part first, then the whole line), but neither worked.
I am stumped! I have clearly messed up somewhere! I do appreciate the help though. All a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

the last selector on your stylesheet, has a space that is causing it not to work. 
`#info :hover` should be `#info:hover`